# Merging dataframes with inconsistent data

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

My friend got asked this question in an interview and we both don't know how to solve it. Would appreciate any help!

**Question:**

I have 2 dataframes that I want to merge together:

Dataframe 1:

[image]

Dataframe 2:

[image]

My thought process is that we need to:

1. Create uniformity in the "Flight Timing" column in dataframe1. Either change it to 3 PM or 15:00. But I am not sure what is the fastest way of doing this.
2. Create a column in dataframe1 with a 2 hour time interval buckets (eg: 3-5 PM)
3. Merge these dataframes on the "time bucket" column created in step 3

I am not sure what is the fastest way to do this in an interview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can `merge` these two dataframes. You probably have to `join` after some preprocessing.

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {
    "A": "9 AM",
    "B": "21:00",
    "C": "3 PM",
    "D": "15:00"
}

timings = ["3-5 PM", "5-7 PM", "7-9 PM", "9-11 PM"]

def convertFrom24HourTo12HourFormat(value):
    """
      function to convert 24 hour date format to 12 hour date format
    """
    # assuming all data is valid
    split = value.split(":")
    
    if len(split) == 1:
        return value
    
    hours = int(split[0])
    
    if hours > 12:
        return "{} {}".format(hours - 12, "PM")
    
    return "{} {}".format(hours, "AM")


def mapTimingToTimings(timingList, timingsList):
    """
      janky function to find out the mapping
    """
    resultTimings = []
    
    # for each timing
    for timing in timingList:
        # find out the range in which it falls
        split = timing.split(" ")
        hour = split[0]
        meridian = split[1]
        
        result = None
        
        for timings in timingsList:
            if timings.startswith(hour) and timings.find(meridian) != -1:
                result = timings
                
        resultTimings.append(result)
    # return it
    return resultTimings    

for key, value in dict1.items():
    dict1[key] = convertFrom24HourTo12HourFormat(value)

df = pd.DataFrame(list(dict1.items()), columns = ["Flight Name", "Flight Timing"])

properTimings = mapTimingToTimings(df["Flight Timing"].values, timings)
df.join(pd.Series(properTimings, name = "Flight Timings"))
```

Output:
[image: Output]

I believe someone else can suggest better optimizations, but considering this was asked in an interview, coming up with optimizations is tough in that context.